# Check if C-style array equals other (compile-time) array

Tags: c++

I've got a `double[9]` and want to check if it contains the values (1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1). Is there a cleaner way than this?

```
if (ornt1[0] == 1 && ornt1[1] == 0 && ornt1[2] == 0
 && ornt1[3] == 0 && ornt1[4] == 1 && ornt1[5] == 0
 && ornt1[6] == 0 && ornt1[7] == 0 && ornt1[8] == 1 )
```

I'm using C++.

Comment: [std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)

Comment: What do you mean by "compile-time vector", as this can be confused with `std::vector`

Comment: You could make a reference array, then use `std::equal` to compare.

Comment: Just that I know what it is at compile-time, namely (1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)

Comment: Put that in a static const array and use `std::equal`. Alternatively use `std::array` which has `==` operator defined.

Comment: If those are the values, then `ornt[i] == (i % 4 == 0)` for all `i`. (Obfuscation joke. Don't do it.)

Answer (score 6):

It is not a good idea to compare double values strictly. I would recommend you create a constant array to compare against and then use a cycle and also use a tolerance(e.g. 1e-9):

```
bool doublesEqual(double a, double b) {
  return fabs(a - b) < 1e-9;
}

const double expected[9] = {1,0,0,0,1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
bool equal = true;
for (int i = 0; i< 9; ++i) {
  if (!doublesEqual(expected[i], ornt1[i])) {
    equal = false;
    break;
  }
}

if (equal) { // do smth
```

EDIT: as suggested by John Zwinck I have edited the code to be able to handle the case when the array we compare contains only NAN. I have edited his suggestion a bit to make the code more readable. Please refer to his comment below for clarification why this is needed.

Comment: Of course you should use std::abs() in C++ rather than fabs().  +1 for being first to point out that exact comparison usually doesn't actually work!

Comment: Consider what will happen if there is a NAN in the array: `fabs(expected[i] - ornt1[i])` will return NAN, and `NAN > 1e-9` will return false, so an array of all NAN will "match" erroneously.  To fix this, change the conditional to `if (!(std::abs(expected[i] - ornt1[i]) <= 1e-9))` (with a comment explaining why, of course, so future maintainers don't break it).

Comment: @JohnZwinck alternatively one can write `equal &&= fabs(expected[i] - ornt1[i]) > 1e-9;`. But in this case I will loose the advantage of early break

Comment: @JohnZwinck you are right of course. We can substitute &= with the bitwise operator, but I definitely don't like this opion

Comment: @JohnZwinck I changed the answer but modified your suggestion a bit to make it easier to read.